# How to calculate the euclidean distance in Python without fixed-dimension?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, scipy, euclidean-distance

I intend to calculate the euclidean distance between two sets of big data. I've googled that the module called [`SciPy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) will do the work, whose mechanism is via k-d tree.

But I don't have fixed dimensions. My data structure is as follows:

```
data1 = {"1": {"a": 1, "b": 2}}
data2 = {"3": {"a": 2, "c": 3}, "4": {"b": 1, "d": 4}}
```

Thus the distance between `"1"` and `"3"` is `(2-1)2 + (2-0)2 + (3-0)2`, and the distance between `"1"` and `"4"` is `(1-0)2 + (2-1)2+(4-0)2`. I hope you can get what I mean.

The essential part is that dimensions like `a`, `b` and `c` are not enumerable. So is there any more efficient way to retrieve the nearest distance between the two sets?

Comment: what happens when you compare two points where `a,b,c,d` are involved? would it be: `(a1-a2)^2+(b1-b2)^2+(c1-c2)^2+(d1-d2)^2`?

Comment: I don't think you're going to do any better than O(n^2), but have you looked at [`numpy.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)? There is also 
[`scipy.spatial.KDTree`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html)

Comment: @Borodin using KDTree is [`O(n log n)`](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/KDTree)

Comment: Sure, all the demensions will be involved. @SaulloCastro

Answer (score 1):

Using `KDTree` is really efficient to find the closest points.

Starting with your data, the first thing is to put in a complete format, where the missing values are filled by zeros, then transform it to arrays and create the `KDTree` (here I am using a `cKDTree` which showed to be faster):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

data1 = {"1":{"a":1, "b":2}, "2":{"a":2, "c":3}, "3":{"c":2, "d":3}}
data2 = {"5":{"a":2, "c":3}, "6":{"b":1, "d":4}}

keys = [a.keys() for a in data1.values()] + [a.keys() for a in data2.values()]
keys = sorted(list(set([a for j in keys for a in j])))

d1 = [[data1[k].get(pt, 0) for pt in keys] for k in sorted(data1.keys())]
d2 = [[data2[k].get(pt, 0) for pt in keys] for k in sorted(data2.keys())]

a1 = np.array(d1)
a2 = np.array(d2)

kd = cKDTree(a1)
```

To find the closest points you do a `query()`:

```
dist, ind = kd.query(a2)
```

where `ind` contains the indices of `a1` that will be closest to each point in `a2`, and `dist` their respective distances.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how many keys there are, it will not be just `"abcd"`. This dimension is **url**, so there will definitely a lot of possible values.

Comment: As said above, it represents **url**, so I don't really know how many there are.

Comment: Seems cool! I'll try it out to see the profile. Thanks for your answer! What if the count of dimension is 1000000? Can numpy hold it? Or will it take too much memory?

Comment: @Judking wow... that's huge. [In the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) it says the efficiency won't be that amazing for more than 20 dimensions... but why would you need so many dimensions?

Comment: It's not my decision. The dimension in my case is **url**, thus the number of dimension will definitely large, at least much more than 20.

Comment: Hey bro, I'm struggling on how to install `numpy` and `scipy` for all the time spent. Why can't I install it correctly. My system is Red Hat 64bit, with python2.7

Comment: @Judking I have no clue... I am on Windows 7 64 bit... try to find compiled packages such as Anaconda ... which will make your life considerably easier...